# How to get the different in number between two browser history

Tags: javascript

I have some browser history input, for example let's assume this is what the history looks like when clicked

```
http://example.com/index.php
http://example.com/profile.php
http://example.com/comments.php
http://example.com/contact.php
```

Now the difference between the index page and the contact page is 3, how can I calculate it

```
var currentPage = "index.php";
var historyPage = "contact.php";
var pageDiff = // historyPage - currentPage
```

Comment: Is the goal to direct the user to go back three pages? If so, why not just direct them there using `window.location`?

Comment: I can't because I want the page to go back so the user can also click the forward button

Comment: Seems like an odd requirement but okay :). Remember this will usually load pages from the browser's cache, so if the contact page is meant to update the index page, it won't be reflected.

Comment: No, it's not meant to replace it. Here is the plan, I already set out a script to detect if the user has accessed the index page before the contact page. So if its true and the use clicks the back button, I want to take them back to the index page ignoring the previous pages he accessed before the contact page. So I will do this, if(user clicks back){ history.go(-3); }

Comment: So the user can also click the forward button to go to the contact page again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the distance between two items in an array, you can use `indexOf`. I'm assuming your browser history is in an array, and not just one big text blob.

Something like:

```
var history = [ 
    'http://example.com/index.php',
    'http://example.com/profile.php',
    'http://example.com/comments.php',
    'http://example.com/contact.php', 
]  
var pageDiff = history.indexOf("http://example.com/contact.php")-history.indexOf("http://example.com/index.php");
```

Comment: I am not the one creating the history so I want to read them from the browsers history.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about how you are going to do that?